# Hashicorp vault pods with pending status

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I deployed hashicorp vault with 3 replicas. Pod vault-0 is running but the other two pods are in pending status.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqeay.png)

This is my override yaml,

```
# Vault Helm Chart Value Overrides
global:
  enabled: true
  tlsDisable: true

injector:
  enabled: true
  # Use the Vault K8s Image https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-k8s/
  image:
    repository: "hashicorp/vault-k8s"
    tag: "0.9.0"

  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 256Mi
      cpu: 250m
    limits:
      memory: 256Mi
      cpu: 250m
  affinity: ""
server:
  auditStorage:
    enabled: true
  standalone:
    enabled: false
  image:
    repository: "hashicorp/vault"
    tag: "1.6.3"
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 4Gi
      cpu: 1000m
    limits:
      memory: 8Gi
      cpu: 1000m 
  ha:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 3    
    raft:
      enabled: true
      setNodeId: true
      config: |
        ui = true

        listener "tcp" {
          tls_disable = true
          address = "[::]:8200"
          cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
        }

        storage "raft" {
          path = "/vault/data"
        }

        service_registration "kubernetes" {}
    config: |
      ui = true

      listener "tcp" {
        tls_disable = true
        address = "[::]:8200"
        cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
      }

      service_registration "kubernetes" {}


# Vault UI
ui:
  enabled: true
  serviceType: "ClusterIP"
  externalPort: 8200
```

Did a kubectl describe into the pending pods and can see the following status message. I am not sure I am adding the correct affinity settings in the override file. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using vault helm charts to deploy to a docker desktop local cluster. Appreciate any help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSo55.png)

Comment: Can you remove this line `affinity: ""` and try again?

Comment: Hi Joshua, welcome to SO. Please don't post textual content as images, since it's hard to read, impairs searching, and is explicitly called out in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. In the future, please ask system administration questions on https://ServerFault.com since this does not relate to programming.

Comment: @mdaniel thanks. Do you think this is a sys admin question? I have seen lot of k8s questions been asked in stackoverflow. Thanks

Comment: @Joshua yes, for sure, because what `if` statement or variable would you change as a resolution to this question? I believe that somewhere on the kubernetes website they're telling people to ask questions on SO, but that's misguided of them since system administration questions are [explicitly listed as off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems in your values.yaml file.

1.You set

```
server:
  auditStorage:
    enabled: true
```

but you didn't specify how the PVC would be created and what the Storage class is. The chart expects you to do that if you enable the storage. Look at: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/blob/v0.9.0/values.yaml#L443
Turn it false if you just testing on your local machine or specify storage config.

2.You set empty affinity variable for the injector but not for the server. Set

```
affinity: ""
```

for the server too. Look at: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/blob/v0.9.0/values.yaml#L338

3.An uninitialised and sealed Vault cluster is not really usable. You need to initialize and unseal Vault before it becomes ready. That means setting up a `readinessProbe`. Something like this:

```
server:
  readinessProbe:
    path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true&sealedcode=204&uninitcode=204"
```

4.Last one but this is kinda optional. Those memory requests:

```
resources:
  requests:
    memory: 4Gi
    cpu: 1000m
  limits:
    memory: 8Gi
    cpu: 1000m
```

are a bit on the higher side. Setting up an HA cluster of 3 replicas with each requesting 4Gi of memory might result in `Insufficient memory` errors - most likely to happen when deploying on a local cluster.

But then again, you local machine might have 32 gigs of memory - I wouldn't know ;) If it doesn't, trim down those to fit on your machine.

So the following values works for me:

```
# Vault Helm Chart Value Overrides
global:
  enabled: true
  tlsDisable: true

injector:
  enabled: true
  # Use the Vault K8s Image https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-k8s/
  image:
    repository: "hashicorp/vault-k8s"
    tag: "0.9.0"

  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 256Mi
      cpu: 250m
    limits:
      memory: 256Mi
      cpu: 250m
  affinity: ""
server:
  auditStorage:
    enabled: false
  standalone:
    enabled: false
  image:
    repository: "hashicorp/vault"
    tag: "1.6.3"
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 256Mi
      cpu: 200m
    limits:
      memory: 512Mi
      cpu: 400m
  affinity: ""
  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true&sealedcode=204&uninitcode=204"
  ha:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 3
    raft:
      enabled: true
      setNodeId: true
      config: |
        ui = true

        listener "tcp" {
          tls_disable = true
          address = "[::]:8200"
          cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
        }

        storage "raft" {
          path = "/vault/data"
        }

        service_registration "kubernetes" {}
    config: |
      ui = true

      listener "tcp" {
        tls_disable = true
        address = "[::]:8200"
        cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
      }

      service_registration "kubernetes" {}


# Vault UI
ui:
  enabled: true
  serviceType: "ClusterIP"
  externalPort: 8200
```

[image: all pods healhty]

Comment: Hi rock'n rolla thank you for all the inputs. Please refer to this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73497048/hashicorp-vault-ha-cluster-pod-in-pending-state