# Vault pod going to crashLoopBackOff state even though it is unsealed

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I have a Hashicorp vault HA-mode deploy for 1 replica. I completed the unseal procedure by providing 3 keys but despite this the pod is still restarting.

To obtain the keys I ran :

```
kubectl exec -it vault-0 -- sh
vault operator init
```

To unseal I ran the following (for 3 unique keys) :

```
vault operator unseal
```

and for the 3rd attempt the pod confirms that it is unsealed :

```
Unseal Key (will be hidden): 
Key                    Value
---                    -----
Seal Type              shamir
Initialized            true
Sealed                 false
Total Shares           5
Threshold              3
Version                1.9.2
Storage Type           consul
Cluster Name           vault-cluster-1g78888f
Cluster ID             8cc8888c-c88d-5858-bd88-8888873f88k4
HA Enabled             true
HA Cluster             n/a
HA Mode                standby
Active Node Address    <none>
/ $ command terminated with exit code 137
```

The output shows that the pod has been unsealed (**Sealed false**) but it immediately restarts.

I have scaled down the deploy from the standard 3 replicas to 1 because of resource constraints on my cluster. Resource/request limits are also scaled down from the standard because of the same resource constraints.

Logs for the pod :

```
 kubectl logs vault-0
     

    Api Address: http://10.222.222.22:8200
                     Cgo: disabled
         Cluster Address: https://vault-0.vault-internal:8201
              Go Version: go1.17.5
              Listener 1: tcp (addr: "0.0.0.0:8200", cluster address: "0.0.0.0:8201", max_request_duration: "1m30s", max_request_size: "33554432", tls: "disabled")
               Log Level: info
                   Mlock: supported: true, enabled: false
           Recovery Mode: false
                 Storage: consul (HA available)
                 Version: Vault v1.9.2
             Version Sha: 873f88k48888873f88k48888873f88k4

==> Vault server started! Log data will stream in below:

2022-06-24T12:02:02.334Z [INFO]  proxy environment: http_proxy="\"\"" https_proxy="\"\"" no_proxy="\"\""
2022-06-24T12:02:02.334Z [WARN]  storage.consul: appending trailing forward slash to path
2022-06-24T12:02:02.394Z [INFO]  core: Initializing VersionTimestamps for core
==> Vault shutdown triggered
2022-06-24T12:03:16.005Z [INFO]  service_registration.consul: shutting down consul backend
```

My vault is deployed with this config : [vault.yml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wTCtMqy-8Cexonu71ZuG8F1oHI5FGQyq/view?usp=sharing)

Consul is deployed with this config : [consul.yml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16QEizytupWRZpIYe_HVGlGfAjxV0F8lL/view?usp=sharing)

Does the procedure for unsealing the vault ***require a quorum of exactly 3 replicas***?

My expectation is that the vault should still unseal ***even when running on 1 replica***.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did the other two Vault servers in the pod join the cluster with Consul? Can you use Raft integrated storage and gossip protocol instead?

Comment: @MattSchuchard how do I check that ? By two servers I assume  you mean vault-1 and vault-2 , if you mean so , I have only 1 replica of vault vault-0 due to resource constraints. If not may you please explain which servers you are referring to - and how do I check if they joined. Any links/pointers for using Raft and gossip protocol also?

Comment: If you only wanted one server in the cluster, then it probably needs to be deployed with Helm inputs for that. Raft can be enabled via https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/blob/main/values.yaml#L719.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I used a custom vault-values.yaml already :  helm template vault hashicorp/vault \
   --namespace labs \
   --version 0.19.0 \
   -f vault-values.yaml \
  > ./manifests/vault.yaml

Comment: and I specified 1 replica/1 server in the vault-values.yaml file. I assume thats what you mean ?

Comment: @MattSchuchard just to confirm if I switch to Raft integrated storage I wont need the consul storage right?

Comment: @MattSchuchard If i swicth to Raft do I still need this in my vault.yaml file : lifecycle:
       
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: [
                  "/bin/sh", "-c",
                  # Adding a sleep here to give the pod eviction a
                  # chance to propagate, so requests will not be made
                  # to this pod while it's terminating
                  "sleep 5 && kill -SIGTERM $(pidof vault)",
                ]

Comment: Here is a working example of vault with working values.yaml file - albeit not with consul as storage backend: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66768436/1722326
Just in case if it proves to be helpful.