# Hashicorp Vault HA cluster pod in pending state

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, hashicorp-vault

We have a private GKE 3 node cluster with 2 vCPU and 8 GB RAM node pool config. We have installed Vault with helm using these [values](https://github.com/shan0809/hashicorp-vault/blob/main/values.yaml).

State of the Vault cluster.

[image]

State of nodes.

[image]

Node usage status.

[image]

State of the **vault-1** pod

###### 1

[image]

###### 2

[image]

State of the PVC

[image]

State of services.

[image]

We referred to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766180/hashicorp-vault-pods-with-pending-status) but no fate.

Please let me know what else info is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's due the **affinity** that is inplace in **values.yaml**

You can try adding the one more node to cluster and check once it will resolve the issue maybe.

it also giving error of **insuffient CPU** so could be one more reason behind the POD stuck in pending state.

Adding one more node will increase the CPU also you can check if there is any affinity issues or not.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Harsh. I will surely follow your advice and publish the results.

Comment: Hi Harsh ... it looks like more of a resource crunch issue. We increased the capacity and the pods are scheduling fine. Hence we are accepting your response as an answer.

Comment: great...! Thanks for sharing the update, glad to know issue is resolved.